# Clarifiaction on the NP-hardness of k-SUM-variants

Tags: complexity-theory, np

I am currently looking into the $k$-Sum Problem and some of its variants. However i stumbled onto an inconsistency, that i can not seem to fix.

If we begin with $3$-Sum, the 'textbook'-definition goes something along the way of

> Let a set $S$ of $n$ integers be given. Are there $a,b,c\in S$ such that $a+b+c=0$.

From this definition however it is not immediatly clear, whether $a,b$ and $c$ have to be distinct. Compare this to [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0925772195000222). In the Introduction they state

> The $k$-SUM problem is the parameterized version of the well known NP-complete problem SUBSET-SUM,and it asks if in a set of $n$ integers, there is a subset of size $k$ whose integers sum to $0$.

This seems to imply, that duplicates are not allowed, as sets usually dont permit duplicates. However in Section 2.2 of the same paper they reduce $k$-SUM to $k$-Table-SUM and link to Section 3.1 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.7558.pdf), where the reduction only works in the case, where duplicates *are* allowed.

Are these two variants equivalent? If so, are there possibly any sources on this? And furthermore, is $k$-Table-SUM NP-hard? Intuition and "closeness" to the $k$-SUM would suggest this, but i haven't found a proof for this apart from the linked sources with the noted inconsistencies.

Thanks!

Edit:

I finally found two sources that can answer this properly. The first contains a reduction from 'Perfect Code' to $k$-SUM without duplicates, however the k-SUM instance is constructed in a way, that allowing duplicates wouldn't find any other solution [here (specifically at 22.5.3)](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.456.2729&rep=rep1&type=pdf). In case anyone is not familiar with perfect code, at 22.2.1 the authors reduce Indepenent Set to Perfect Code.

The second source actually links to the first. They reduce $3$-SAT to $k$-SUM [in Theorem 5.1](https://people.csail.mit.edu/mip/papers/sat-lbs/paper.pdf). Note that the proof specifically states, that they seperate the instance into d blocks, and then make sure that $k$-SUM only finds one entry per block. This is exactly the same as $k$-Table-SUM and also easily reduced to $k$-SUM with duplicates, similar to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes in case of 3-sum problem they are equivalent. Let $P$ be the version where the three numbers have to be distinct and $P'$ the version where you can use the same number multiple times. The reduction $P'$ to $P$ is by solving the cases with overlapping in preprocessing (since both overlapping cases can be done in almost linear time).

The other direction is a bit more complicated. We will reduce $P$ to another variant $P''$ and from $P''$ to $P$. We start by defining $P''$: given three sets of integers $A,B,C$. Can we pick a number from each to sum to zero.

$P''$ to $P'$ is quite easy. Let $M$ be the largest number in all sets. Let $U := 3M + 1$ build the set $$S := \{a+U:a\in A\} \cup \{b + 2U: b\in B\} \cup \{c-3U:c\in C\}$$ as input to $P''$. Try to prove why the reduction is correct as an exercise.

Now the last reduction from $P$ to $P''$ is a bit more complicated. It is actually randomized. Fix a correct tripple in $S$. A random partition of $S := A\dot\cup B \dot \cup C$, we will have the numbers in the triple assigned to distinct sets with probability at least $2/3 \cdot 1/3 = 2/9$. By repeating a constant factor of $\log n$ you get a running time of $O(n\log n)$ reduction with high probability.

Comment: Interesting, thank you for your input! I have actually proven this redcution from $P''$ to $P'$ in the more general case of $k$-sum already. And your randomized reduction in the end should also work for $k$-sum with a probability of $k!/k^k$. Are you aware of a derandomized approach?

Comment: No not really. I would find it interesting if you found one. Please post any new resources you find :)

Comment: I've edited the question for two sources that do not necessarily answer the derandomized reduction, but answer the NP-hardness on $k$-SUM with duplicates.